# JNA java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library './OUNPPM'

Tags: java, jna

So, I have a project that uses a series of external C `.dll`s and it works fine when running in Netbeans, but when I try to run the `.jar` by itself, I get this error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library './OUNPPM': The specified module could not be found.

I've encountered this before for a few different reasons:

1) Not finding the file.
2) Not finding another .dll that .dll is dependent on.
3) Trying to load a 64-bit .dll with the 32-bit JRE (or vice versa)

Is there any way to get a better error message to find out what is going on?  JNI gave better errors, but I'm not really at a place I can change those right now.

Comment: The one who came with this error message: *Unable to load library './OUNPPM'* deserves to be shot ;)

Comment: Your #2 reason (Not finding another .DLL . . .) was the cause of my instance of the "`...UnsatisfiedLinkError...`".  I was able to figure this out by using a tool called "DependencyWalker" and specifying foobar.DLL as the file to examine.  The tool gave me a list of files that the foobar.DLL was depending on, but which it did not have access to.  I made an intelligent guess as to which one was most likely the cause of the error and got lucky, for obtaining a copy cleared up my error.  This even though there were ~8 other files that still were not available to the foobar.DLL.

Answer (score 0):

when you are launching the main class in your jar file, how are you running it and have you set your jna.library.path.

If your `jna.library.path` points to the location of the correct dlls then you shoul dnot get those errors.

Comment: I don't set the jna.library.path in either Netbeans or from the command line.  Is it set for me inside Netbeans automatically?  Also, is '.' not automatically in the path?

Comment: System.setProperty( "jna.library.path", ".");

With the .dlls in "." did not seem to work either.

Comment: oh, and I just run with with

java -jar "NAVAID.jar"

and when run in Netbeans without setting it, it says jna.library.path is null, but still works.